# What is most Unusual in Paragraph?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, story

The paragraph below is most unusual. How quickly can you find out what is so unusual about it? It looks so ordinary you'd think nothing was wrong with it - and in fact, nothing is wrong with it. It is unusual though. Why?

"Gatsby was walking back from a visit down in Branton Hill's manufacturing district on a Saturday night. A busy day's traffic had had its noisy run; and with not many folks in sight, His Honor got along without having to stop to grasp a hand, or talk; for a mayor out of City Hall is a shining mark for any politician. And so, coming to Broadway, a booming bass drum and sounds of singing, told of a small Salvation Army unit carrying on amidst Broadway's night shopping crowds. Gatsby, walking towards that group, saw a young girl, back toward him, just finishing a long, soulful oration ... "

The above passage is taken from the book "Gatsby" written by Ernest Vincent Wright in the late 1930's.

What is unusual about the paragraph above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possibly:

> that there is no letter **e** in the quoted paragraph?

and its unusual because

> The letter **e** is the most common letter used in the English language (thanks [BeastlyGerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51835/what-is-most-unusual-in-paragraph/51836#comment158802_51836))

As a bonus although it might not have any relevance:

> The title of the question has no **e**'s either

Comment: You may want to include that the thing that is special about the letter 'e' is that [it is the most common letter in english](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency)

Comment: That's interesting. Do you know if it was intentional or just a coincidence that had just been noticed? Would there be a stylistic reason for doing that?

Comment: @Forklift: The book is Gadsby, and the entire book has no letter E.

Comment: Ah. I was skimming and thought he said the book was "The Great Gatsby," which I am familiar enough with to know it is not devoid of "e" (the many "eye" references for starters).

Comment: @Deusovi Yes sir you are right. Letter 'E' most commonly used in English language but I heard in this book Gatsby haven't use E.  BeastlyGerbil and indubitable You guys Awesome. Cheers to Puzzling family 